# bash: run command multiple times with list of values

Tags: bash

I need to run a command several times, each time with a new value:

```
grep VALUE0 myfile.txt
grep VALUE1 myfile.txt
grep VALUE2 myfile.txt
```

Because the grep command is "crafted" ad hoc (not always the same) and only the list of VALUEs is always the same I don't want to put the grep-command into a loop inside a bash-file.
I would prefer to maintain my list of VALUEs in a seperate file like "values.txt" and let an ad-hoc shell command loop over this list of values read from "values.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `grep` manual:

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)

You could create a file with the patterns, one per line, and just run `grep -f patternfile …`. Perhaps it doesn't fit you, but it's difficult to know without explicit examples.

Comment: This is cool! I was looking more for the xargs way, but this one seems even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using `xargs`:

```
xargs -a values.txt -I {} grep {} myfile.txt
```

This means that the file `values.txt` is read, one line at a time, then the command `grep ... myfile.txt` is run, where `...` is being replaces with the content of the line read (I used `{}` because that's what `find` also uses.)

That being said, I can also tell you that with

```
egrep 'VALUE0|VALUE1|VALUE2' myfile.txt
```

you can search for more than one text at a time.

Comment: Cool, xargs seems to be exactly what I was looking for! The second idea is interesting as well. Thanks for both!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read value
do
    grep $value myfile.txt
done < values.txt
```

Keep the `values` in `values.txt` file, each in separate line.

Comment: Thanks. I did not want to put the grep statement inside the batch file, because it changes everytime. Thanks anyway.